# Office plant identification and care - my 2nd plant

Tags: identification, plant-care, office-gardening

Since [my previous question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/office-plant-identification-care) about the plant at my office is so well received, I thought it would be nice to get some information about another plant at my office.

A picture of my plant can be seen below.

So, by that, I have the same questions from my previous:

- What's the name of this plant?
- What is the best way to take care of this plant?

[image: My office plant]

Comment: Hummmm...is there a hole at the bottom of this pot?  How old is this plant?  Not looking happy at all.  What are you doing with fertilizer, what kind of water and what kind of soil (please tell me you didn't use garden or outdoor soil)...is there a hole at the bottom of this pot?  Who planted this pot?  Did they use rock/gravel at the bottom of the soil? Are you using tap water as well?  Mostly I am worried about the drainage...how long have you had this plant????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plant is an [Anthurium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthurium), a member of the aroid family, who are identified by the flower structure of the [spathe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathe) and spadix.

- high intensity filtered light, not direct. If it doesn't flower then the light levels are too low
- a free draining soil such as peat moss, perlite and pine bark
- water thoroughly and let dry
- underwatering or low humidity levels will give brown tips to the leaves
- fertilize at half strength every other month with a flowering plant fertilizer. Something like 15-30-15.
- pests: [scale](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scale) and [mealy bug](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/7730/499) are possible, [thrip](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3906/what-are-these-black-spots-on-white-splotches-appearing-on-my-tomato-seedling/3980#3980) have been seen but are uncommon in a house or office